# Tests are not loaded using unittest.TestLoader() after using a decorator on my unittest.TestCase class

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, decorator, python-unittest

I have a test as a subclass of unittest.TestCase which I use a decorator on.

```
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver
import sys

SAUCE_USERNAME = 'xxx'
SAUCE_ACCESS_KEY = 'xxx'
sauce = SauceClient(SAUCE_USERNAME, SAUCE_ACCESS_KEY)
browsers = [{"platform": "Mac OS X 10.9",
     "browserName": "chrome",
     "version": "31"},
    {"platform": "Windows 8.1",
     "browserName": "internet explorer",
     "version": "11"}]


def on_platforms(platforms):
    def decorator(base_class):
        module = sys.modules[base_class.__module__].__dict__
        for i, platform in enumerate(platforms):
            d = dict(base_class.__dict__)
            d['desired_capabilities'] = platform
            name = "%s_%s" % (base_class.__name__, i + 1)
            module[name] = new.classobj(name, (base_class,), d)
    return decorator

@on_platforms(browsers)
class MyTestSuite(unittest.TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.desired_capabilities['name'] = cls.id()
        sauce_url = "http://%s:%s@ondemand.saucelabs.com:80/wd/hub"
        cls.driver = webdriver.Remote(
        desired_capabilities=cls.desired_capabilities,
        command_executor=sauce_url %     (SAUCE_USERNAME,SAUCE_ACCESS_KEY))
    cls.driver.implicitly_wait(30)

def test_1from_sauce(self):
    pass

def test_2from_sauce(self):
    pass

@classmethod
def tearDownClass(cls):
    cls.driver.quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
     suite =unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(Registration)
     unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=1).run(suite)
```

The problem is when I run this code using CLI, I get this error:

```
File "MyTestSuite.py", line xxx, in <module>
    suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(Registration)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/unittest/loader.py", line 50, in loadTestsFromTestCase
    if issubclass(testCaseClass, suite.TestSuite):
TypeError: issubclass() arg 1 must be a class
```

This error goes away when I comment out the `@on_platforms` decorator. Also when I am using this decorator, `MyTestSuite type is "Nonetype"` and when I remove it, type of MyTestSuite changes to `"type"`. Where is the issue coming from?

Answer (score 0):

Your decorator is changing the signature of the object it is decorating.  Graham Dumpleton explained this issue in extreme detail [here](http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2014/01/implementing-factory-for-creating.html).  Try using [Decorator](https://github.com/micheles/decorator/blob/3.4.2/documentation.rst) from pypi to decorate your decorator to make it preserve the signature of what it is decorating.